# Linq with MySql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, linq, sql-server-express

Is there a free solution for using Linq and MySQL?

Can one use Visual Studio Express, Linq, and MySQL together?

Comment: I don't know which to try.   Can we get some votes for preferred methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **[interlinq](http://www.codeplex.com/interlinq)**
- **[DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/)**

If you want Visual Studio integration and designer you should check [**MindScape LightSpeed**](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/). Though I doubt it will work with express edition, it provides free edition for small database.

Comment: Regarding LightSpeed, you're right, there's no designer in VS Express.  However you can still use it "code only" and get the LINQ to MySQL that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nhibirnate and linq. http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/16/Linq-for-NHibernate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

An answer to [this question on the Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/e9fc6bc7-fbc6-44c4-b37b-4b4a83beaa3e) would indicate that you can.

> Yes, you can.
>
> Use LINQ for NHibernate.
>
> http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/16/Linq-for-NHibernate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Entity Framework and [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Connector/Net is the managed ADO.Net provider for MySQL and has support for Entity Framework (this was added in version 6.0, the connector is at 6.1 at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, check out these links:

- [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
- [MSDN Microsoft QuickStart to Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx)

Just install the connector, follow the quickstart and you'll be ready to work with Entity Framework.